# SED Command to remove first digits and spaces of each line

Tags: sed

I have a simple text file in below format.

```
1  12658003Y
2  34345345N
3  34653785Y
4  36452342N
5  86747488Y
6  34634543Y
so on
10  37456338Y
11  33535555Y
12  37456378Y
so on
100  23432434Y
```

As you can see there are two white spaces after first number.

I'm trying to write SED command to remove the digits before whitespaces. Is there any SED command to remove spaces and number before spaces?

Output file should look like below.

```
12658003Y
34345345N
34653785Y
36452342N
so on..
```

Please assist. I'm very new to shell scripting.

Comment: Did you see the [manual](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sed+manual) yet?

Comment: If you don't absolutely need `sed` you can try with `grep -o '[0-9]+Y'`

Comment: @SandeepDongapure since you are back in the site, you can consider accepting an answer here as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sed command would be,

```
sed 's/.* //g' file
```

This would remove the first numbers along with the space followed.

Comment: No, that greedily matches everything before the last space, plus the space.

Comment: Right, sorry, it *would* work with this data, because there are only two fields. Not as robust as it could be, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+\s\+//' infile > outfile
```

Explanation:

**s:** we want to use substitution

**/:** mark start and end of the expression we want to match

**[0-9]:** match any digit

**+:** match the previous one or more time

**\s:** space

**+:** match the previous one or more time

**/:** mark start of what we want to change our matches to (which is nothing)

**/:** some special operators goes after this (we use no such)

**infile:** the file we want to change

**>:** pipe stdout to

**outfile:** where we want to store output

Comment: Note that `\+` is a documented GNU extension, and `\s` seems to be an *undocumented* one, as far as I can tell. They may not work with other versions of `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove leading digits, then following spaces:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]* *//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^[0-9]*[ ]*//g' input.txt
```